# Where is the civicrm database?

Tags: database

I recently took over a website and I have missing tables in the civicrm database (under wordpress). I want look at the civicrm database but I don't know where the database is stored. How can I find the physical civicrm database file so I can download it and run some queries to see what's there?  When I go to phpMyAdmin on the server, it only lists the wordpress database.

Below is what I see when I look at phpMyAdmin and this is the only db. I have looked at all of the table names in this db and there are no civicrm tables.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can find the civicrm database listed in the civicrm.settings.php

```
 <wordpress>/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
```

Apart from that , you have two possibilities

1)Wordpress and Civicrm both use same database

2) Civicrm has    separate database

If wordpress and civicrm has same database , you can search in wordpress database tables which have prefix civicrm_*

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but there are no civicrm tables in the WP db. I found a database name in civicrm.settings.php, but I can't find a file with that name on the server. In theory, it shouldn't be that hard to find the file, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you want, I can help you figure that out.let me know

Comment: I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @kzburn, I would have helped if I ws able to access your environment

Comment: Hi @kzburn, check for r9Z99F_2_civicrm_* as prefix in your database list of tables

Comment: Log in to phpmyadmin using the username/password listed in the same place in civicrm.settings.php where you found the database name. It might be different database users for wordpress and civi.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you are in the correct database for your wordpress your civi is installed on, you should see this.

[image]

****EDIT****

Go to wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Look for this line

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_DSN') && CIVICRM_UF !== 'UnitTests') {
```

define( 'CIVICRM_UF_DSN'           , 'mysql://**YOUR CIVI DATABASE LOCATION SHOULD BE RIGHT HERE**');

Comment: When I go to phpMyAdmin, I only see one database.

Comment: See my edits above.  That should help you find your civi database location.

Comment: Thanks.....I found that and I know the name of the database, but when I ftp to our server, there isn't a file there with that name.  At least I'm on the right track. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You won't see it with ftp, you would see it in phpmyadmin, but you might be logging in to phpmyadmin as a user that doesn't have access to the civi database. Use the user/pass that's listed in the CIVICRM_UF_DSN setting.